# Why can you not use an initializer block for a static variable in an inner class?

Tags: java, static, declaration, inner-classes

why does java not allow static declarations with a static initialization block in a non-static inner class?

in the below code, outer2 will work and inner2 will not, despite doing the same thing. any ideas? i'm not looking for a workaround, i'm just trying to understand why java fails to do this.

```
public class WhyUNoStatic {
    public static final String outer1 = "snth";  // ok
    public static final String outer2;  // ok
    static
    {
        outer2 = "snth";
    }

    public class Inner {
        public static final String inner1 = "snth";  // still ok! 
        public static final String inner2;  // FAILURE TIME
        static
        {
            inner2 = "snth";
        }
    }
}
```

edit: note that `inner1` will work fine. it's not that java prohibits static vars in inner classes, it just prohibits declarations of them.

Comment: Because inner classes cannot have `static` non final members, and `static { }` is a static member. Maybe?

Comment: Java prohibits non-constant variables in inner classes. `inner1` is a constant variable. `inner2` is not.

Answer (score 2):

The [JLS, Section 8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3), disallows this behavior.

> It is a compile-time error if an inner class declares a static initializer (§8.7).
>
> It is a compile-time error if an inner class declares a member that is explicitly or implicitly static, unless the member is a constant variable (§4.12.4).

You declared your `static` variables `final` in your inner class, which is ok, but the static initializer is prohibited there.

Comment: And as for the reason why, it probably would've complicated the already quite complicated initialisation sequence even more.

Comment: yeah, that's what i'm trying to get at. why can the compiler not handle this? i'd love to see a code example to show why it's difficult for the compiler to deal with this...

Answer (score 2):

See [JLS Chapter 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html)

> Inner classes may not declare static initializers (§8.7) or member interfaces, or a compile-time error occurs.

You can declare a nested class instead

```
public static class Inner {...}
```